# What was the origin of the Atavus (atavi?) in Season 5?

Tags: earth-final-conflict

I've heard conflicting versions of the genesis of these guys- were they hibernating in those stasis chambers all along or were they created by the last Taelons and Jaridians merging?

Answer (score 1):

The Atavus were (mostly) there all along, and it was merely the efforts of the Taelons and Jaridians to join that awoke them, although some of them may have been formed from former Taelons.

As revealed in prior episodes, Atavus were an earlier evolutionary form of the Taelon race. Da'an briefly turned into an Atavus when he was separated from the Taelon collective unconscious, in the episode Atavus.

[image]

Later episodes, in an effort to help the two separate races, Atavus technology already on Earth was used, including a resurrection chamber, to fix the problem with the Taelons and Jaridians... which suggests they were already on Earth (some of this may have been retconned in in the final season, it was a long time ago, and I can't remember if they explicitly said it was Atavus technology before S5 or if the implication it was just ancient Taelon technology that they later decided was Atavus).

In any event, after the merging a new, lower-makeup-budget version of the Atavus appeared on Earth.

[image]

Once the Atavus returned in force (after Liam Kincaid tried to join the two other races), their leader was Howlin.  Howlyn was explicitly an Atavus who had been on Earth thousands of years ago, rather than a Taelon/Jaridian hybrid, and told how his race went into hibernation because of deadly meteor showers.

When he converses with Rene, he expresses surprise at how humanity has changed, their appearance and clothing, which makes it pretty clear he was there at the time and not some new merged being.

> Howlyn: This is our planet.  We came, we conquered, we altered lifeforms and the ecosystem, even introduced some of our own.  Were it not for the Asteroid swarm that forced us underground into stasis, you wouldn't even exist.

Many of the S5 episodes revolve around finding more Atavus hives that are still in hibernation, to increase the race's numbers, but these tombs had nothing to do with the Taelon/Jaridian joining, and as such they had to have already been there for some time.  In S5, Episode 8, "Entombed" they found one of these tombs that had been breached in the 16th century.  A episode summary site explains:

> Flying by ID shuttle to the site, they find two pods, one that was apparently breached by a 16th century knight, killing the Atavus inside, and the other containing the deceased Atavus' mate.

They also on occasion suggest that the Atavus are responsible for some of humanity's legends like Demons and Vampires.

Of additional note, Zo'or was resurrected and turned into an Atavus in episode 5.09, "Boone's Assassin."  While this suggest that it's possible that after the existing Atavus like Howlyn woke up, they took advantage of the weakened state of some of the Taelons and used them to increase their numbers, the fact that Zo'or kept their memories suggests that that, unless this was a special process, or the Atavusified Taelons didn't bother talking about their history, this didn't happen to any other Atavus under Howlin's command.

In any event, the series of events was pretty confusing.  Season 4 ended with the two races joining and not revealing what happened.  Season 5 began with this new alien race.  It's natural to assume that the new race was the result of the joining.  However, paying close attention makes it clear that the Atavus were merely awakened and either killed the other two races, or the others merely didn't survive the attempt to join (save one Taelon).  It also didn't help when they keep throwing in ambiguous lines like, when Rene first meets Howlyn,

> We were trying to save the Taelons and the Jaridians.  Obviously something went wrong and we got you.

Sandoval also occasionally had lines that suggested the Atavus were a result of the merging, not that their awakening was an unfortunate but unrelated side-effect.

I suspect part of the problem was that they didn't know what they were going to do at the end of season 4, and finally went with a drastically different storyline for season 5 that didn't entirely fit in with everything else they'd been setting up.  Also, bad writing in general plagued the series and especially the last season.